# Tensorflow Training Speed with ADAM vs SGD on (Intel) MacBook Pro CPU vs (AMD) GPU with Apple Metal

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization, metal

I am playing around with Tensorflow Metal in Python 3.8 (https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) with my 2019 MacBook Pro (2.3 GHz Intel Processor, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M GPU)  which allows me to use my AMD GPU to accelerate tensor flow calculations. I tried running this example in two different virtual environments; one with apple metal (GPU support) and another without.

```
import tensorflow as tf

cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
include_top=True,
weights=None,
input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
classes=100,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=\["accuracy"\])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

With my CPU this takes about 15 minutes, with my GPU it takes a half hour *after* the training starts (which I'd assume is after the GPU overhead has been accounted for). To reiterate, the training has already begun (the progress bar and eta are being printed) when I start timing the GPU one, so I don't think that this is explained by "overhead", although I could be wrong. That being said, changing the optimizer to ADAM via:

```
import tensorflow as tf

cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
include_top=True,
weights=None,
input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
classes=100,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss=loss_fn, metrics=\["accuracy"\])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

changes things a ton. Running it in the environment with GPU support takes about 4 mintues, the CPU environment takes 12-13 minutes.

I  used activity monitor to ensure that my GPU is being used when it's supposed to, and not being used when it's not supposed to. Does anyone have any idea on why this might be? I know SGD is simpler than ADAM, so it makes sense for SGD to be faster than ADAM in the same environment. I'm confused as to why the CPU would be so much faster when using that optimizer?